# Firebase Cloud Messaging not getting registered second time

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making use of Firebase Cloud Messaging to send me push notifications in my iOS application. I am listening to the notification of `kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification` in my AppDelegate. Once the app delegate gets the device token in `application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)`, my selector method of `kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification` is getting called.

My problem is, once the user signs out and then signs in again, this time however after the device token is received in `application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)`, my selector method of `kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification` is not getting called.

As an observation point, the selector method doesn't get called after the first time it is called (even if user doesn't sign out).

I am enclosing my required code below. Let me know if any other parts of code is necessary. Please can somebody explain me where I am going wrong in this.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder {
      func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tokenRefreshNotification(_:)), name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)
         return true
      }

      func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
          FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)
      }

      func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
           print("Called only first time")
      }

     func loginFirebaseWithFacebookAccessToken(accessToken: String) {
          let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(accessToken)
          if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
               user.linkWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                   print("Sign in done")
               }
          } else {
               FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                   print("Sign in done")
               }
           }
     }

    func signOutFromFirebase() {
        do {
            try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
        }
        catch {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Prasad, I also faced same problem, Did it work for you any chance?

Comment: @Maheep, I didn't get any solution still.

Answer (score 1):

actually i tried this lines, works for me:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

   [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] deleteIDWithHandler:^(NSError *  _Nullable error) {
       // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil]; 
   }];
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to force the logout ? 
try! FIRAUTH.auth()!.signOut()

Comment: Yes. It is of no use.